# R libraries not loading despite being specified in environment.yml file

Tags: r, package, jupyter-lab, virtual-environment, jupyter-irkernel

In the environment file, made with conda, the dependencies specified are:
r-cowplot
jupyterlab
r-irkernel
nb_conda_kernels

When I open Jupyter with this environment, and with the kernel set in this environment, and do:

```
library(cowplot)
```

I get:

```
Error in library(cowplot) : there is no package called ‘cowplot’
```

I deleted and created the env from the env file a couple times, to no avail.

Comment: Hmmm...that seems like you aren't actually starting Jupyter with the r kernel in the correct environment even though you think you are. You need to specify better in your post how you are starting things. Or are you sure you have the channels right and cowplot is installing? You really only share a little about the `environment.yml` file here. If at this point you just want to get past this hurdle, open Jupyter as you would for running the notebook you want but then open a new notebook with a Python kernel and run `%conda install conda-forge::r-cowplot` in a new cell in that new ...

Comment: <continued> notebook, based on [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/r-cowplot) and the magic install commands that insure the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel is running. (I said to use a Python kernel because I think the magic works there and not the rkernel but they probably will share the same environment if you start the same way.) Let it run successfully, then shutdown everything again and restart as you were and try the `library(cowplot)` in your r-backed notebook now.